# Chain fp-ts TaskEither with Either in right

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I have a flow of 2 nested request, where could be 3 different results:

1. One of requests return Error
2. User is not Anonymous, return Profile
3. User is Anonymous, return false

Both requests could throw an error, and becaues of that implements `TaskEither`

```
const isAuth = ():TE.TaskEither<Error, E.Either<true, false>>  
   => TE.tryCatch(() => Promise(...), E.toError)
const getProfile = ():TE.TaskEither<Error, Profile>  
   => TE.tryCatch(() => Promise(...), E.toError)
```

The first request returns the boolean status of user authorization. Second request loads user profile **if the user is authorized**.

In return, I want to get the next signature, Error or Either with Anonymous/Profile:

```
E.Either<Error, E.Either<false, Profile>>
```

I tried to make it this way:

```
pipe(
    isAuth()
    TE.chain(item => pipe(
      TE.fromEither(item),
      TE.mapLeft(() => Error('Anonimous')),
      TE.chain(getProfile)
    ))
  )
```

But in return, I get `E.Either<Error, Profile>`, witch not convenient because I have to extract `Anonymous` status by hands from `Error`.

How to solve that question?

Comment: `E.Either<true, false>` doesn't make much sense because the type is `Either<boolean, boolean>`, so you cannot get an `Either<boolean, TypeOfProfile>` anyway. The reason why you lose the `Either` layer is the natural transformation `TE.fromEither(item)` from `Either` to `Task` you perform as the first step of your composition.

Comment: Oops, just noticed that your initial Either has literals as type parametrs and hence is `Either<true, false>`. The Issue remains the same though.

Comment: @bob yes, I user natural transformation to make it work, because I don't find a way to write correct pipe, that will return `E.Either<false, Profile>` or `Option<Profile>`, which is not a point, in the right part, and put Error from the second request to Left part - it's what my question about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if you oversimplify actual code, but `E.Either<true, false>` is isomorphic to just `boolean`, so let's stick with simpler thing.

```
declare const isAuth: () => TE.TaskEither<Error, boolean>;
declare const getProfile: () => TE.TaskEither<Error, Profile>;
```

Then you add condition branch based on whether its authed or not and wrap the result of getProfile:

```
pipe(
  isAuth(),
  TE.chain(authed => authed 
    ? pipe(getProfile(), TE.map(E.right)) // wrap the returned value of `getProfile` in `Either` inside the `TaskEither`
    : TE.right(E.left(false))
  )
)
```

This expression has type `TaskEither<Error, Either<false, Profile>>`. You probably need to add some type annotations for it to typecheck properly, I haven't run the code myself.

**EDIT:**

You probably need to extract lambda as named function to get proper typings, something like so:

```
const tryGetProfile: (authed: boolean) => TE.TaskEither<Error, E.Either<false, Profile>> = authed
  ? pipe(getProfile(), TE.map(E.right))
  : TE.right(E.left(false));

const result: TE.TaskEither<Error, E.Either<false, Profile>> = pipe(
  isAuth(),
  TE.chain(tryGetProfile)
);
```

Comment: It works thank you!
But how to get the correct types? 
I tried this `A.sequenceT(TE.taskEitherSeq)(result)`, but in return, I get Array type `TE.TaskEither<Error, [E.Either<false, Profile>]>`, which is not what I am looking for :(
Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @IvanTarasov Not exactly sure, maybe there is an error or a typo. I updated the answer with some typing suggestions, you can work from there, it should give you some sensible  compiler errors.